# Bash when i try to apped to a string its overwrite

Tags: string, bash, concatenation, git-bash

i run the following function in (git-)bash under windows:

```
function config_get_container_values() {

local project_name=$1
local container_name=$2

#local container_name="gitea"

echo "###"
buildcmd="jq -r \".containers[]."
echo "$buildcmd"
buildcmd="${buildcmd}${container_name}"
echo "$buildcmd"
buildcmd="${buildcmd}foobar"
echo "$buildcmd"
echo "###"

}
```

The output of this is the following. Whyever, after using the variable to extend the string, he starts to overwrite $buildcmd. I tried this also with everything in one line as well with the append command (=+). Everytime the same result.

```
###
jq -r ".containers[].
jq -r ".containers[].gitea
foobar".containers[].gitea
###
```

The really strange thing is: When i enable the line `local container_name="gitea"` everything works as expected. The output is:

```
###
jq -r ".containers[].
jq -r ".containers[].gitea
jq -r ".containers[].giteafoobar
###
```

When i put this all into a news file, its also works as expected. So i think something goes wrong in the thousands of line before calling this function. Any idea, what could be cause of this behavior?

Regards

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how you should build up the command, DOS line endings aside. Use `--arg` to pass the name into the filter as a variable. For example,

```
config_get_container_values() {

  local project_name=$1
  local container_name=$2

  jq -r  --arg n "$container_name " '.containers[][$n+"foobar"]'
}

config_get_container foo gitea < some.json
```

Answer (score 0):

If the function is invoked with

```
config_get_container_values proj gitea
```

it produces the "expected" output.  If it is invoked with

```
config_get_container_values proj $'gitea\r'
```

it produces output that looks like the first output example.  `$'gitea\r'` expands to a string that consists of `'gitea'` followed by a [Carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) (CR) character.

One possible cause of the problem is that the container name (`gitea`) was read from a file that had Windows/DOS line endings (CR-LF).  Problems like that are common.  See the first question ("Check whether your script or data has DOS style end-of-line characters") in the "Before asking about problematic code" section of the [Stack Overflow 'bash' Info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info).